# select2 from json based on other input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to populate a `CITY` select based on selection on `PROVINCE` with select2.

I've some problems:

1- `PROVINCE`: It's populated by default, but i get duplicate elements. In my example i get:

```
Milan
Milan
Torin
Torin
```

but i'd like to get:

```
Milan
Torin
```

Solved by @david: http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/282/

2- Based on `PROVINCE` select, i need to populate `CITY` ONLY with subarray. For example if I select `Milan` on first select, i need to get `CITY` like:

```
Rho
Other city
```

I don't know how to filter.

Solved by @david: http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/282/

3- Fieldbox filter of select2 doesn't work. If I insert "MI", Torin still display

4- Based on @david solution http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/282/, i've to return PROVINCE array in alphabetically order. In my example is already done cause i've only 2 items inserted and already ordered..

This is my original fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/218/

Comment: Does your json data in the same file as javascript file?

Comment: no, it's saved as data.json in the server. I've posted a json inside a variable for semplicity only for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `if` statement on your processResults.

Check the `processResults` in the province.

```
processResults: function (data) {
    var a = [];
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            if (!a.includes(obj.provincia.nome)) {
                a.push(obj.provincia.nome);
                return { id: obj.provincia.codice, text: obj.provincia.nome };
            }
        })
    };
}
```

This is the `processResults` in the city selection.

```
processResults: function (data) {
    return {
        results: $.map(data, function(obj) {
            if ($('#province').val() == obj.provincia.codice){
                return { id: obj.nome, text: obj.nome };
            }
        })
    };
}
```

In the province selection, declare an array for storing the province name. If a province name is already inside the array, don't show the duplicate.

In the city selection, just check the province code with the selected province code.

Comment: Thank you! It solves points 1 and 2 perfectly. Now i've to solve point 3 and how to order PROVINCE array alphabetically. I think i'll open another post for this purpose. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. If you don't mind, you can mark my answer as accepted. It will help anyone who might encounter similar problem with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Its an issue related to the object that you are reading.
The object that is being parsed has provincia.name = 'Milan' at two places and 'Torin' at two places.

The select2 functionality is working fine, the issue is with the object being 'read'.

Comment: This is the original json I need to manipulate. I'm looking for a method to return UNIQUES values...