# Return json sorted from select2 and fiter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to populate a `CITY` select based on selection on `PROVINCE` with select2.

Thanks to @david i've solved some problems (original post: [select2 from json based on other input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51241676/select2-from-json-based-on-other-input-field/51242401))

But now I've some problems:

1- I've to get PROVINCE json result in alphabetically order. So in my example i've to get:

```
Milan
Parme
Torin
```

2- Select2 "filter input box" doesn't work 'cause i get a fixed json from server side (I get json from a file to the server: in my example i've used a json variable for semplicity). For example if i type `MI` in PROVINCE select, I'm still getting all results

This is my last fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/290/

Answer (score 0):

Sorting the results by the province name can be done in the `processResults` option.

Filtering the results should ideally be done on the server side. If you must do it locally, you can do so in the `data` setting of the `ajax` option.

I updated your Fiddle to reflect these changes:
http://jsfiddle.net/pe1u6Luo/389/

I used [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) to sort and filter the results.